# Cúando intento utilizar una tarjeta inteligente con dni electrónico a la hora de firmar me produce una excepción

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un documento XML que quiero firmar con un dni electrónico conectado a través de una tarjeta inteligente, cuando intento firmar con un certificado digital con extensión .pfx me lo firma correctamente, sin embargo cuando intento firmar con el dni electrónico me arroja este tipo de excepción:

[image: Excepción que me arroja]

Aquí les dejo el código que firma el documento y la línea donde se produce la excepción:

```
 public int SignXml(XmlDocument xmlDoc, X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        _resultado = 0;
        try
        {
            if (xmlDoc == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("xmlDoc");
            }
            if (cert == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Cert");
            }

            // ESTO FUNCIONA CUANDO NO ES UNA TARJETA INTELIGENTE.
            var exportedKeyMaterial = cert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true);
            var key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(new CspParameters(24));
            key.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            key.FromXmlString(exportedKeyMaterial);
            
            
            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
            signedXml.SigningKey = key;
            signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";

            Reference reference = new Reference();
            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
            reference.Uri = "";
            signedXml.AddReference(reference);

            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
            keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));
            signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

            signedXml.ComputeSignature();
            XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
            xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
         }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _resultado = 1;
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            
        }
        return _resultado;
    }
```

A la hora de firmar, saco la ventana con los certificados y me aparece el dni electrónico, y me arroja la excepción que he propuesto antes:

[image: Certificados disponibles en la máquina local]

Agradezco toda ayuda que me puedan aportar, gracias.

Saludos.

Comment: Parece ser un excepción controlada, y no veo donde te la lanza a la excepción, solo mostras si son null, hay otro metodo que lanza o los catch, y lo que te dice que hay un metodo que no acepta algun parametro que le pasas.

Comment: Edite la pregunta y puse la parte del catch que no puse cuando la formulé inicialmente